# Как создать подключение DSL на Linux Open-SUSE12.1?

Tags: сеть, opensuse, dsl, suse, linux

У меня NetworkManager не работает. YaST  DSL-поюключение не создает требует скачать пакет mpppd кажется.

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего сбросить настройки АДСЛ-модема на заводские, в системе выставить автоматическое получение IP-адресов, войти в модем файрфоксом на адрес 192.168.0.1 под именем admin и прописать выданные провайдером имя и пароль прямо в модеме - и инет всегда подключен будет, что в винду зайдете, что в линукс. Такова общая схема, подробнее в инете смотреть надо, дефолтный пароль admin'а напр. не помню.